# Handle orientation change with running AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask

**Use case:**

The user start the app that will load a captcha. The user fill the captcha and try to download some information.

**Problem:**

If the user rotate the device while downloading the `Activity` is destroyed. At the end of the execution the AsyncTask is trying to update the destroyed `Activity` and the **result** is a **"View not attached to window manager".**

**"Wrong" solution:**

I can mask the problem with a `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` but with this the layout is not going to be updated to landscape.

*What I'm asking:*

Is it possible to change the orientation and change the "reference" of the Context passed to the `AsyncTask`?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224676/android-view-not-attached-to-window-manager#6240320) suggest to check if the dialog is not null, but it's not what I'm looking for.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111980/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-progress-dialog-and-background-thre#4481297) he suggests to use a WeakReference ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220625/android-context-leaks-in-asynctask#4220746) a nice snippet on how to use it) but I didn't understand if it's what I'm looking for.

To be more explicit this is what I'm doing in the onPostExecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Auto result) {
    progress.dismiss();
    new DownloaderCaptcha(context).execute("");
    ((EditText)context.findViewById(R.id.editTextCaptcha)).setText("");
    context.findViewById(R.id.progrBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    context.findViewById(R.id.captcha).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if(result != null) {
        Storage.storeHistory(context, result.getTarga().getValue());

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MenuActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("result", result);
        context.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        ErrorDialog.show(context, error);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the best answer but you could keep a ref on your asyncTask and pass it to your landscape activity. The landscape activity would then update asynctask context... But I don't know what will happen if your ascncTask finish during the activity transition (but there are simple solutions to this issue).

Comment: @matiash: no need to downvote, also because if you look at the time when the answer was posted, it was right after Alex post this one! So at the time there wasn't a good answer to my question. Obviously you can flag it as a duplicate, but a downvote is meant a lack of research, not my case I guess. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Enrichman I didn't downvote it. I agree it's a good question, it's just a duplicate one.

Comment: @matiash yes, no problem, I thought it was you since the flag. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are my tips:

- Do **not** use `android:configChanges` to address this issue.
- Do **not** use `Activity#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to address it either (as this approach is deprecated).
- Instead, use a retained worker `Fragment`. I've recently [**posted an article**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) describing how to handle configuration changes using retained `Fragment`s. It solves the problem of retaining an `AsyncTask` across a rotation change nicely. You basically need to host your `AsyncTask` inside a `Fragment`, call `setRetainInstance(true)` on the `Fragment`, and report the `AsyncTask`'s progress/results back to it's `Activity` through the retained `Fragment`.

Comment: I'm encountering some issues trying to implement this but I guess it's the best solution. Thanks. :)

Comment: I like this answer so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

> "Wrong" solution:
>
> I can mask the problem with a
>   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" but with
>   this the layout is not going to be updated to landscape.

Actually it will.

> android:configChanges Lists configuration changes that the activity
>   will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the
>   activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a
>   configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being
>   restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its
>   onConfigurationChanged() method is called.

Take a look  at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

You can implement the layout for both Landscape and Portrait modes or to cancel your AsyncTask on configuration change.

Comment: Of course I have. It will change the orientation but the layout used is the one defined for the portrait mode.