# How activity leak happen in this code

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

By passing activity object to the constructor of the AsyncTask. Is there any possibility of 
Activity leaking. if so then how it happen, can anyone please explain this. and how to avoid the activity leaking if it happening.

```
public class RemoteLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Activity activity;

    public RemoteLoader(Activity context){
      this.activity = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... Pages) {
        // do in bg
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set title into TextView
        TextView txttitle = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.txtProtip);
        txttitle.setText(protip);
    }

}
```

Comment: try to change the orientation when asynctask is running.

Comment: is there any way to avoid it Mr Raghunandan :)

Comment: Read this: http://corner.squareup.com/2013/12/android-main-thread-2.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220625/android-context-leaks-in-asynctask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AsyncTask` keeps a reference to the `Activity`, therefore the `Activity` instance cannot be `garbage collected` while the `AsyncTask` is `alive/running`.

In certain cases, such as orientation change, the *"old"* `Activity` instance is no longer required as another `Activity` instance is created by the framework. In such cases, if your `AsyncTask` is keeping a *strong reference* to the `Activity` instance, then there will be a memory leak.

To avoid this issue, use `WeakReference` as follows:

```
public class RemoteLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private WeakReference<Activity> activity;

    public RemoteLoader(Activity context){
      this.activity = new WeakReference<Activity>(context);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

When using `WeakReference` you can ensure that the `Activity` instance is garbage collectable if needed. You can read more about `WeakReference` [here](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references).

Answer (score 1):

Try having a WeakReference to your Activity in the AsyncTask. And upon completion, check if the Activity still exists.

Comment: do you have any example