# How exactly does AyncTask behave in this situation?

Tags: android

There is an AsyncTask that fetches something from the web and then calls Activity.showDialog in onPostExecute(...).
What exactly happens if

1. I start AsyncTask in Activity B
2. Go back to Activity A
3. AsyncTask finishes it's job (doInBackground() returns)

? Is onPostExecute() called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the fact that my Activity finishes has no effect on the AsyncTask. I have showDialog() call in my onPostExecute(). This is causing force close when the user presses BACK, the Activity finishes and onPostExecute() is called.

Comment: You should always check before creating a dialog, if you still have context/activity you can work on.

Comment: Yes... I am using this pattern - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821423/background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working/3821998#3821998. I will have to do a small modification to fix this bug. Right now I am detaching my Activity from the AsyncTask in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(). I will move the detach to onDestroy(), which should solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how your AsyncTask is implemented you might "leak" Activity B until the AsyncTask finishes. Ideally, your AsyncTask should be cancelled when Activity B is destroyed.

Comment: My AsyncTask is a static class, reference to the Activity is set by setActivity() method. I return the AsyncTask in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() - and after orientation change I retrieve it with getLastNonConfigurationInstance() and call setActivity(). I see WindowManager.BadTokenException reports in Android Market, can it be caused by the way how I use AsyncTask?

Comment: @fhucho: Possibly. You cannot safely reference the `Activity` from `doInBackground()`. If you avoid that and call `setActivity()` again from `onCreate()` of the new activity instance, in theory, you should be safe. Leastways, that was the net result of an exchange I had with Ms. Hackborn on the `android-developers` group some time ago.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using the pattern you described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821423/background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working/3821998#3821998 (please see my comment). However I noticed I don't detach the Activity, which could be the problem.