# OK to read values in the UI thread from an AsyncTask.doInBackground()

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, android-asynctask

In Android, is it OK to read values that exist in the UI thread (e.g. an Activity subclass's member fields) from an `AsyncTask.doInBackground()`, just not try to write them?  Or should reading only be done in `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you don't touch an activity within `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`. The reason: configuration changes (e.g., screen rotations). The activity might be replaced while the thread is chugging along, and therefore you might wind up reading from the wrong activity.

If you follow the recipe I outline in [this answer over yonder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821423/background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working/3821998#3821998), and you synchronize access to the `Activity` being held by the `AsyncTask`, you'll get as good of results as possible. Of course, you will also have to deal with thread safety of whatever it is you're reading ("e.g. an Activity subclass's member fields"), as they may or may not be thread-safe already.

Comment: Thanks. Does the same reasoning apply to `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: @Julian: No, because `onPostExecute()` is called on the main application thread. And, if you follow the recipe I linked to above, the activity instance in the task will be the right one by the time `onPostExecute()` executes.