# Save object while orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to save Object while orientation change, since [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) and [getLastNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) are deprecated. And which cannot me used with `compatibility package` `android-support-v4.jar` `FragmentActivity`, where it shows `Cannot override the final method from FragmentActivity`

developer site say

> Use the new Fragment API setRetainInstance(boolean) instead;

But I don't know how to save a custom object using [setRetainInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)

**My scenario :**
In my activity I have a AsyncTask with progress dialog. Here I need to handle orientation change.
For that I got a very good answer from Mark Murphy, CommonsWare
[background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821423/background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working/3821998#3821998),
with [sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation/RotationAsync/)

Since I'm using compatibility package android-support-v4.jar, `FragmentActivity`, I can't override `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`
*Cannot override the final method from FragmentActivity*

Is there any alternative method for saving my custom object?

**EDIT:**
I cannot make my AsyncTask task Parcelable (If I'm not wrong) since it use interface, context etc.
My `AsyncTask`

```
 public class CommonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>  {
        Context context;
        AsyncTaskServices callerObject;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        String dialogMessag ; 
    ................
```

I'm looking, is there any **alternatives for onRetainNonConfigurationInstance** method, which save an object completely while orientation change and later can be retrieve using `getLastNonConfigurationInstance`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two alternatives:

1. Use a `Loader`. The `FragmentActivity` will take care of saving/restoring its state when re-creating.
2. Use a fragment without a view and call `setRetainInstance(true)` on it. There is an example of this in the compatibility library's source, FragmentRetainInstanceSupport or some such.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay Elenkov for directing me to `loader`, after a big fight I have done it using `loader` inside a `fragment`

Comment: Could you tell me how you handled the show/dimiss of the progress dialog since these fragment transactions are forbidden in onLoadFinished?

Comment: Use `FragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()`. Sounds dirty, but there seems to be no other way. Or, better yet, don't use a progress dialog. Use the action bar spinner (indeterminate progress) or something else. Dialog are usually not worth the trouble.

Comment: Interesting. Has this been added recently? I don't remember seeing it before.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov Is this not appropriate if your fragment does have a view?

Answer (score 43):

You can use [onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance%28%29)

> Use this instead of onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(). Retrieve later
>   with getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance().

Comment: That's just the same as `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` which the questioner is explicitly trying to avoid (in the first sentence of the question no less!)

Comment: No, it's not the same.  See docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance\(\)  The OP did not say that he was trying to avoid using onRetain...(), he just said it wasn't compiling since it has been declared final in the support lib (which is all true).  I think this solution is valid as a holdover / workaround while migrating to the new way of doing things.

Comment: Sometimes I feel these APIs were made more complicated then they should be.

Answer (score 5):

When your Fragment is paused it will call this method:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Add variable to outState here
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

The variable `outState` will then be fed into the onCreate() method when the Fragment restarts.

You can save any data that is a basic type or implements `Parcelable` interface

Comment: See my edit, I cannot make my AsyncTask task Parcelable (If I'm not wrong) since it use interface, context etc..

Comment: Uhm... Please leave a comment of /why/ you downvote an answer otherwise we won't know why it's factually incorrect?

Comment: I agree with that _down vote with comment will help_. But here I have no idea what/who give you that (_I can't see any down vote_)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the bundle will be available in the onCreate method, not onCreateView or onViewCreated like I was trying.

Comment: Will this also be called when a fragment is replaced?

Comment: I'm not sure - I would imagine not because when a fragment is replaced it has .remove() called on it, effectively destroying it, it will never be resumed. Try it out yourself, it should be a pretty easy test to carry out.

Answer (score -1):

Well, quote from `Android Developers' References`:

> This method is called after onStart()  when the activity is being
>   re-initialized from a previously saved state, given here in
>   savedInstanceState. Most implementations will simply use
>   onCreate(Bundle)  to restore their state, but it is sometimes
>   convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done
>   or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default
>   implementation. The default implementation of this method performs a
>   restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).

Regarding the use of `onSaveInstanceState()`, it's better to revert your objects/things by using `onRestoreInstanceState()` instead.

[Refer to Activity#onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: See my edit, I cannot make my AsyncTask task Parcelable (If I'm not wrong) since it use interface, context etc.. to use with `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: `onRestoreInstanceState()` is not a replacement for `onSaveInstanceState()` - infact it is entirely useless without it. The quote merely mentions in some instances it is more convenient to use `onRestoreInstanceState()` over `onCreate()`.