# What is a good way to inform the user about the progress?

Tags: android

There are many ways to inform a user about the current progress e.g. `Dialog`, `ProgressBar`, `Toast` and many more.

[CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) told me that he

> avoid dialogs like the plague

because he want to

> let the user use whatever of the app that they can while that loading is going on

so I'm interessted in, how do you handle this?
what do you prefer?

In fact, that the user could do what he want there's also the possibility that he makes something what changes the activity. How do you inform the user now about the progress?

Comment: probably add something to the notification bar when the process is done - then when they press it it takes the user back into the app

Comment: The #1 question, IMHO, is whether the work in question is of relevance only to one activity, is relevant to the whole app, or is relevant to the user even if the user leaves the app. For example, the `Notification` approach is a wonderful one for things like downloading purchased digital goods, particularly if those goods are not intrinsically tied to your app (e.g., download an MP3). So, to really get proper answers for your question, you need to explain completely and precisely what it is that you are doing that involves "progress" and how that relates to the rest of the app and to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a **`sticky notification`** with a **`Progress Bar`**,
so the user can use your app in the *'loading time' and
when he wants to look up the **`Progress`**,
he pulls down the **`notification bar`**, and voila.
if you want, you can make a **`Toast`** when the task finished.