# What is an empty process in android and what is it’s use?

Tags: android

What is empty process in android and what is it’s use.
I have seen empty process in my device sometime and it shows process with 0 services ,0 activities means process with no components inside it .
I also want to know if as a developer,it's of any use or it's just useful on OS level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is empty process in android

It is a process with no running activities, services, or broadcast receivers (and where nothing presently is connected to one of the app's content providers, if any, though this is a fairly obscure case).

> what is it’s use

Once upon a time, the process *did* have activities, services, and/or broadcast receivers. However, those components were destroyed as a part of their normal operation (e.g., a manifest-registered receiver returned from `onReceive()`). Right now, the process is being held onto, just in case that a process for the same app is needed again. Eventually, though, the empty process will be terminated, to free up system RAM for other processes.

> I also want to know if as a developer,it's of any use or it's just useful on OS level.

Mostly, it is an OS-level optimization to improve device performance and responsiveness, compared with terminating the process immediately when the last running component was destroyed.

Comment: @CommonsWare does that mean, empty process is a state of a process where the process has completed the task it is supposed to do, and waiting for OS to terminate it?

Comment: @VinodAkkepalli: Yes, that is a reasonable description.

Comment: So. when i close down an app on my phone using recent apps button( lets say) an empty process is created...?

Comment: @c_mnon: I do not know what "close down an app" means. If you are using the overview screen (recent tasks list) to switch to a new task, whatever activity was in the foreground simply moves to the background. There is no immediate impact on the process. Android 5.0+ devices allow you to swipe an entry off the overview screen; this should terminate your process, at least if you have no services running. A process becomes empty if the user uses BACK to navigate out of all running activities within that process, or those activities are `finish()`-ed by other means.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks.You understood my query very well considering lack of clarity in my question...!!! Let me just retell the thing to make sure I understand correct. So if i use BACK to navigate out of the running activities that process becomes empty, but still will be using up RAM. but if I use the swipe off overview screen, I terminate the process(5.0+) and all the RAM is freed up. ( I want to make sure I have maximum free RAM available - kind of thing !!)

Answer (score 2):

> **What is Empty process?**

*Process that doesn't hold any active application components.*

> **What is it use?**

The only reason to keep this kind of process alive is for caching purposes, to improve startup time the next time a component needs to run in it.

The system often kills these processes in order to balance overall system resources between process caches and the underlying kernel caches.