# Android Layout folder is not changing properly

Tags: android, screen

my android layout is not changing the layout folder on orientation change below is my layouts and the permissions i am giving to my activity. But by default when i open portrait or landscape it is working properly but if i change from default portrait to landscape or default landscape to portrait it is not changing. Is there anything like we should not change layout structures and drawable which we are using.

```
     //My activity permission
       <activity
        android:name="com.pro.sample.Distributor1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        </activity>


   //This is my sw-600dp-port
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:id="@+id/distributor_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/home_back" >
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/row_1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="ZipCode:"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:textColor="@color/White"/>
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/search_zip_code"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ems="10"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:background="@drawable/edit_field_back"
         android:maxLength="5" >

         <requestFocus />
     </EditText>
           <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Or"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:textColor="@color/White"/>
               <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="City:"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:textColor="@color/White"/>
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/search_city"
         android:layout_width="180dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ems="10"
         android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
         android:background="@drawable/edit_field_back" >
         <requestFocus />
     </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/row_2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="State:"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:textColor="@color/White"/>
      <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/search_states"
         android:layout_width="180dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
         android:entries="@array/state_names"
         android:ems="10"
         android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
         android:background="@drawable/edit_field_back" >
     </Spinner> 

               <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Miles:"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:textColor="@color/White"/>
     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/select_miles"
         android:layout_width="180dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/near_miles"
         android:ems="10"
         android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
         android:background="@drawable/edit_field_back" >
     </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/search_distributor"
                 android:layout_width="100dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:background="@color/White"
                 android:text="Search"
                 android:textSize="22sp" />
             <TextView android:id="@+id/dist_head"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Distributors Near You"
                 android:textColor="@color/White"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:textSize="25sp"/>"

             </LinearLayout>
          <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          </ListView>
         </LinearLayout>


     //This is my sw-600dp-land

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:id="@+id/distributor_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/home_back" >
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/row_1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:gravity="center" >

      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="ZipCode:"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:textColor="@color/White"/>
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/search_zip_code"
         android:layout_width="180dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ems="10"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:background="@drawable/edit_field_back" >

         <requestFocus />
     </EditText>
           <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Or"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:textColor="@color/White"/>
               <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="City:"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:textColor="@color/White"/>
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/search_city"
         android:layout_width="180dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:ems="10"
         android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
         android:background="@drawable/edit_field_back" >
         <requestFocus />
     </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/row_2"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:gravity="center" >
      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="State:"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:textColor="@color/White"/>
      <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/search_states"
         android:layout_width="180dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
         android:entries="@array/state_names"
         android:ems="10"
         android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
          >
     </Spinner> 

               <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Miles:"
         android:textSize="22sp"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:textColor="@color/White"/>
     <Spinner
         android:id="@+id/select_miles"
         android:layout_width="180dp"
         android:layout_height="40dp"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/near_miles"
         android:ems="10"
         android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
          >
     </Spinner>
     </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/search_distributor"
                 android:layout_width="100dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:background="@color/White"
                 android:text="Search"
                 android:textSize="22sp" />
             <TextView android:id="@+id/dist_head"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Distributors Near You"
                 android:textColor="@color/White"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:textSize="25sp"/>
              </LinearLayout> 

            <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           </ListView>
         </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout will not be change when you are roatate the device because of

**android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"**

When you define android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" in your AndroidManifest file,
it means that you are indicate to the android system that don't change the layout when phone is rotated.

Remove this then check again.

I hope this helps...:)

Comment: @ at the manali i tried android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" why because i dont want to call my asynchoronous task again is there any other way to achieve both...

Comment: You probably use AsyncTask for asynchronous task right? Have a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821423/background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working/3821998#3821998

Answer (score 0):

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
```

This means that you will handle configuration changes by yourself. This is not a good practice if you use this as "solution" for rotation changes.

More on [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818717/why-not-use-always-androidconfigchanges-keyboardhiddenorientation).

Answer (score 0):

android:configChanges="orientation" says Andoid API that you handle orientation change yourself. Remove "orientation" from manifest, it should be `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"`

Comment: This is not accurate. screenSize also happens when orientation is changed on API13+