# (Android) Using getActivity() causes a memory leak but adding get application context causes bad token exception

Tags: java, android, memory, asynchronous, task

The main class extends Fragment and Implements onclicklistner.

this snippet is from my async task.

Any ideas of how to get the application text within fragment classes?

As far as I understand there is a timing/calling issue somewhere which causes the memory leak. Would I have to declare a Context variable maybe?

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.tracklist_fragment_view_fragment, container, false);

    Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sendtofriend);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new GetDataTask().execute();
}       

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {         

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {         
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        pd.setTitle("Grabbing Track!");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }
```

LOGCAT >>>

```
01-13 10:15:01.511: W/dalvikvm(11829): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4163a970)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:623)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:269)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at com.superbit.swipeexperiment.TrackListFragment$GetDataTask.onPreExecute(TrackListFragment.java:79)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at com.superbit.swipeexperiment.TrackListFragment.onClick(TrackListFragment.java:64)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4280)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17984)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
01-13 10:15:01.521: E/AndroidRuntime(11829):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 10:15:02.923: D/Process(11829): killProcess, pid=11829
01-13 10:15:02.923: D/Process(11829): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:123 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

code relating to getActivity();

```
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            final String responseServer = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                    responseHandler);

            final String formattedTrack = responseServer.trim().replaceAll(
                    "\\s+", " ");

            parts = formattedTrack.split("\\=",-1);
            final String trackName = parts[0].toString();
            final String youtube = parts[1].toString();

            values.add(trackName);                              

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {         
        SetListViewAdapter();
        pd.dismiss();
    }

    private void SetListViewAdapter() {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), R.layout.custom_listview, values);
        lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (values.size() == 2) {
            values.remove(0);
        }

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {


                VideoFragment f = VideoFragment.newInstance(parts[1].toString());
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.youtube_player_frag, f).commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821423/background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working/3821998#3821998

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line-

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

with-

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

beacuse you need the progressdialog only in the Activity you are in.

Comment: Originally I was using getActivity() however after a few cycles through the code it causes a memory leak. this is the logcat...

Comment: 01-13 10:38:51.089: E/WindowManager(13841): Activity com.superbit.swipeexperiment.Main has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42fafb10 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,486} that was originally added here

Comment: leaked window error comes when you finishes your activity before finishing your progressDialog. So, first dismiss the progressDialog and then finish the activity related to that.

Comment: This is where my problem lies, I dismiss the progress dialog in the on post execute method. I have tried changing where the code is executed but still the same issue.

Comment: @JessonAtherton show your that code and log related to that problem

Comment: there is the rest of the class including the list view class. I cant put the whole class because it's for a production app.

Comment: call SetListViewAdapter() after pd.dismiss();

Comment: 01-13 11:15:59.747: E/WindowManager(17907): Activity com.superbit.swipeexperiment.Main has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41f23c50 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,486} that was originally added here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this,

write the code in a UI thread and make pd static to avoid leakage

```
public static ProgressDialog pd;

getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override                                               
public void run() {
     pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            pd.setTitle("Grabbing Track!");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();
    }
});
```