# Android external Async Task with callback, do i need to dispose the callback?

Tags: java, android

Got a small issue and would like some advice on it.

This is my Async task

```
public class DummyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private OnDummyTaskComplete mOnDummyTaskComplete;

    public DummyTask(OnDummyTaskComplete listener) {
        mOnDummyTaskComplete = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        mOnDummyTaskComplete.onDummyTaskComplete();
    }
}
```

This is my callback

```
public interface OnDummyTaskComplete {
    void onDummyTaskComplete();
}
```

This is the activity that implements the callback starts the async task.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnDummyTaskComplete {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DummyTask dummyTask = new DummyTask(this);
        dummyTask.execute();
    }
```

Do I need to dispose of the callback to avoid a memory leak?
Is the following code required?

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    mOnDummyTaskComplete.onDummyTaskComplete();
    mOnDummyTaskComplete = null;
}
```

Comment: Is `DummyTask` declared as an inner class in `MainActivity`, or in a separate file?

Comment: @pathfinderelite, hi it is in a separate file

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to dispose of the callback to avoid a memory leak?

No.  Shortly after `onPostExecute()` is run, the `AsyncTask` instance will lose scope, along with its reference to `mOnDummyTaskComplete`.  Just be sure not to reference `mOnDummyTaskComplete` (or anything else that may contain a reference to `MainActivity`) from within `doInBackground`; otherwise, you do open yourself up to a `Context` leak. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821423/background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working/3821998#3821998) related SO issue for details.